# CanvasJs not displaying line in .asp

Tags: asp.net, canvas, html5-canvas

Guys the problem i have with it is that i am not able to see the line chart's line and points. i am pretty sure that the chart is working because when i hover across it, i am able to see the data points. Please help, thanks!

This is the JavaScript for it.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    window.onload = function () {
        var dataPoints = [{ y: 10 }];
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            backgroundColor: "red",
            title: {
                text: "Dynamic Data"
            },
            axisY: {

            },
            data: [{
                type: "spline",
                color: "yellow",
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }]
        });

        chart.render();

        var yVal = 15, updateCount = 0;
        var updateChart = function () {
            yVal = yVal;
            updateCount++;

            dataPoints.push({
                y: yVal
            });

            chart.options.title.text = "Update " + updateCount;
            chart.render();
        };
        // update chart every second
        setInterval(function () { updateChart() }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

This is the body for it.

```
<div id = "chartContainer" style = "height: 300px; width: 100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the issue.Can you share more details like the browser & CanvasJS library version. Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suyashsingh/u01n7gn1/) for your code without any modification.

```
var dataPoints = [{ y: 10 }];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    title: {
        text: "Dynamic Data"
    },
    axisY: {
  },
   data: [{
        type: "spline",
            color: "yellow",
            dataPoints: dataPoints
        }]
    });

    chart.render();

    var yVal = 15, updateCount = 0;
    var updateChart = function () {
        yVal = yVal;
        updateCount++;

        dataPoints.push({
            y: yVal
        });

        chart.options.title.text = "Update " + updateCount;
        chart.render();
    };
    // update chart every second
    setInterval(function () { updateChart() }, 1000);
```